# by default where the data is stored in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

simply i take mvc 3 project then add model "class1" in that there is another class "person"
in class1 there is two properties id,name and
in class person i inherits dbcontext class and it contains

"public DbSet classes { get; set; }"

and i take default1controller with read/write actions and views, using entity framework and
set
model class "class1" and
data context class "person"
so now my program runs successfully
and i can insert the data but i don't know that where it stores the data.
plz help me.

Comment: Can you retrieve the inserted data after clearing your cache and re-starting Visual Studio?

Comment: finally i got the solution i have seen that it stores the data in my local sqlexpress

Answer (score 1):

It might use [SQL Server Compact](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx) which stores data in a file inside the `~/App_Data` folder.

Comment: i've also checked that folder is empty

Comment: @ManishG, maybe you have a local SQL Express Server? Look at the connection string in your web.config. It will indicate you where data is stored.

Comment: i forget to write that i have no any connection string at anywhere not even in web.config

Comment: finally i got the solution i have seen that it stores the data in my local sqlexpress

Answer (score 0):

I've not yet used MVC 3 but have a look at your Visual Studio solution. See if there is an App_data folder and expand that. In there you might see an MDF database. Chances are the data is stored in there.

Comment: finally i got the solution i have seen that it stores the data in my local sqlexpress

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I would add to @ManishG's comment:

> it stores the data in my local sqlexpress

is that, for connecting to a sqlexpress instance, you should put (local)\SQLEXPRESS in the Server Name field if you are creating a connection from VS 2010 Server Explorer.